# На одной из страниц выпадает 401. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/api/challenge/getfiltered",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        sort: { columnName: "createddate", direction: "desc" },
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Всё ок);
    }
});
```

Я не разлогиниваюсь.
    На смежных страничках ajax прекрасно работает.
    Подскажите - в чём может быть проблема

Comment: На других страницах к этому же ресурсу обращаетесь? Проверьте заголовки запроса, в частности куки

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov, нет, на других ресурсах используется то же API, но другие контроллеры. Хорошо, спасибо за совет